# SQL, Oracle, Updating from two tables using a where statement

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I am trying to update the `status` from the `SALE_HEAD` table. The `PRODUCT` table has to read the `min_quantity` where if it is between 0 and 200 then `status` from `SALE_HEAD` is updated from `'a'` to `'b'`.

table structure:

---

### sale_head

sale_num - pk auto

sale_date

status

staff_id - fk to staff

cus_id - fk to customer

---

### sale_line

product_code - pk and fk to product

sale_num - pk and fk to sale_line

quantity

acutal price

---

### product

product_code - pk auto

description

stock_count

restock_level

min_level

list_price

product_manual

assembly_program

Comment: Show table structure

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this

```
 update sale_head
 set staus='b'
 From sale_head s Join (select sale_num,product_code,quantity from sales_line s
 inner join product p  on p.product_code=s.product_code 
 and p.min_level=s.product_code ) as t1 on t.sale_num=s.sale_num
```

Comment: I am getting the following error: 

Error starting at line : 1 in command -
update SALE_HEAD
 set STATUS = 'B'
 where SALE_HEAD.ID in 
 (select ID from PRODUCT where MINIMUM_LEVEL between 0 and 100)
Error at Command Line : 3 Column : 8
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "SALE_HEAD"."ID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: @user2797402 give your table details

Comment: @user2797402 minimum of quanity ah ? or quanity between 0 to 200 ah

Comment: Sorry Min_Level (is min_quanity) = between 0 and 100

Comment: Sorry Min_level = Min quantity

Comment: @user2797402 now try it